# Working with images (playing cards)

Tags: android

What is the best way of working with images, for a playing cards game in my case?
Defining a resource for each image I have seems a little overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience defining a Resource for each card is the way to go. Not all devices will have the memory required to slice a single large bit map. Once you have all the cards in individual resources you can use a static initializer to put the references into a convenient data structure. Also you can give them a specific naming scheme to make the generation easier and generating multiple decks of different styles of cards by using [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind the fact that ids can be itrated, they are in an order.

```
int a = R.drawable.image1;
a++;
if(a == R.id.image2)
{
//this will always be true.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check these out:

[The card game,along with the source code.](http://code.google.com/p/bestcardgameever-android/)

[The programmer discusses the methodology he adopted(to a certain extent).](http://developreality.blogspot.in/2009/05/overcoming-absolutelayout-deprecation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode has characters for spade, diamond, heart, club. 
Maybe you could have just one resource for a blank card and place these characters and number over the blank card image